# Trying to get this to work on a button (on click) so that it fills/updates another field in the same row

Tags: javascript, button

```js
function myFunction() {
    var w = document.getElementById("QTY_r.0").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("Cycle.0").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("Requestedr.0").value;
    var x = +z - +w + +y
    document.getElementById("Returnedr.0").value = x
}

function calculate1() {
    cycle = Number(this.getField("Cycle.0").value);
    requested = Number(this.getField("Requestedr.0").value);
    qty = Number(this.getField("QTY_r.0").value);
    Number(this.getField("Returnedr.0").value = String(Requested - Total + Cycle);
}

("Returned.0").value = Number(this.getField("Requestedr.0").value) - Number(this.getField("QTY_r.0").value) + Number(this.getField("Cycle.0").value);
```

Comment: Please include more information in your post/question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.